# Yarn problem with Windows when creating React app

Tags: windows, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use Yarn to create a react app (I named it sagas2) and I'm getting this error.

I think it is because my Windows username has a space (Name lastname).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is issue because of having space in your path. It is a know issue if your are using npx as mentioned in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512

Instead you can try below as a work around:

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app my-app`